# Xcode 5: how to enable "reopen last projects/windows"?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I'm stumped. Xcode 5 - the final and public release only - will no longer automatically re-open the previously open projects when restarting Xcode. This feature always used to work, up to and including the Xcode 5 GM seed.

I can't find anything regarding "open last windows" or similar in System Preferences. It used to be on the General page. This is all there is in my version:

[image]

Does anyone know how to re-enable this feature, and can you confirm that it is gone? Or do I have a broken Xcode?

Comment: Same for me. I think it's gone.

Comment: Strangely enough when Xcode crashes it reopens the last recently opened projects.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

This is actually an os x feature. Under "System Preferences" and then "General", there is a checkbox that says "Close windows when quitting an application". This needs to be unchecked to reopen windows. This is what I had to do to get the opposite effect of what you want and can confirm this works.

In previous os x 10.7- it's ""Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps", and needs to be checked to work.

Comment: Thanks! The setting (at least on Mavericks) is called "Close windows when quitting an application" and was checked. Unchecking fixed it. I assume Apple added this after they introduced the auto-reopen feature in 10.8 which was frustrating, ie preview reopened your last couple dozen images every frickin' time. Seems like I can remove Enemy of the State now.

Comment: Is there any way to make it not open the organizer window on start?

Comment: In OX 10.10.4, The setting is now the reverse: `Close windows when quitting an app`

Comment: Still the solution in Nov 2017.

Comment: Solution still applicable as of Nov 2018, but following the description as @ChrisConover

Comment: Does not work for me on Big Sur 11.4 and Xcode 12.5. Despite unchecking the `Close windows when quitting an app` Xcode opens as an empty shell window and I have to go to `File > Open Recent`.

Comment: Does work for Ventura 13.5. The setting has changed location though: `System Settings...> Desktop & Dock > Windows & Apps` toggle off the `Close windows when quitting an application`.